# Row calculated from existing rows given some condition

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm really new to Power BI, I'm a data analyst and usually work with code, so I'm not really familiar with Excel like formulas

I have a table with like 20 columns, and I need only 2 columns for this calculation, so I'm going to zoom in the columns I need:

[image]

I want to add rows with Attribute5 for which is  Attribute1 - Attribute2 - Attribute3.

The result should look like this :

[image]

I'm really stuck with this since yesterday morning

I achieved it with a Measure by:

1. Creating a table containing distinct attributes :

```
TableXX = UNION(DISTINCT('Table'[Attributes]),{{"Attribute5"}})
```

2. Doing the calculating with a measure :

```
    Measure = 
    SUMX (
        DISTINCT ( 'Table 3'[Attributes] ),
        SWITCH (
            'Table 3'[Attributes],
            "Attribute5", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ), 'Table'[Attributes] = "Attribute1" )
                - CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ), 'Table'[Attributes] = "Attribute2" )
                - CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ), 'Table'[Attributes] = "Attribute3" ),
                var a = 'Table 3'[Attributes] return
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),'Table'[Attributes]=a)
        )
    )
```

But I don't really want a measure, I want to replace Value Column by this measure, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new table as the union of the existing table and a calculated table that has the new rows that you want:

```
NewTable =
VAR Table5 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            'Table 3',
            'Table 3'[Attributes] IN { "Attribute1", "Attribute2", "Attribute3" }
        ),
        'Table 3'[Date],
        "Attributes", "Attribute5",
        "Value", SUMX (
            'Table 3',
            IF (
                'Table 3'[Attributes] = "Attribute1",
                'Table 3'[Value],
                - 'Table 3'[Value]
            )
        )
    )
RETURN
    UNION ( 'Table 3', Table5 )
```

The new calculated table is stored in the variable `Table5` which takes only the rows containing attributes 1, 2, or 3 and for each date takes the sum of the values where attributes other than 1 get a negative sign.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the easiest way is to pivot `Values` column, so you will get a table with columns `Date`, `Attribute1`, `Attribute2`, `Attribute3` and `Attribute4`:

[image]

Then add a custom column `Attribute5`:

[image]

And then unpivot attributes columns to get the table back:

[image]

Comment: You mean pivot Attributes by assigning the values column to "Values" ?

Comment: Yes, this is how I made it.

Comment: I already tried that but idk somehow, on the real data the values on the pivoted columns are false when i do this x)

Comment: I tried deleting the other columns and keeping only the 3 columns mentionned below, it worked, do you know how can i do to keep those columns ?